# Проверка существования календарного дня

Tags: java, дата

У меня есть 3 числа **int**: year, month, day, которые должны соответствовать дню календаря.

Можно ли с помощью каких-либо стандартных библиотек проверить, что такой календарный день существует?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static boolean isDateValid(int year, int month, int day) {
    boolean dateIsValid = true;
    try {
        LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        dateIsValid = false;
    }
    return dateIsValid;
}
```